# How to import external ssl certificate into java local keystore?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ldap, certificate, keystore

I need to import ssl certificate into java local keystore(cacerts) in order to get access to the remote ldaps server.
I have run the following command:

```
keytool -keystore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts -import -alias myalias -file <PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE>/certificate.cer
```

The certificate successfully added to the keystore:

```
keytool -list -alias myalias -keystore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts
Enter keystore password:
myalias, 24.10.2019, trustedCertEntry
```

My application properties:

```
  ssl:
    key-alias: myalias
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

When I run the app I have the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1210)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:328)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
    ... 20 more
```

I am using Spring boot 2.2.0

Who knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your application.properties is, you are securing your springboot application. Which is different from what you are trying to do (call ldaps server).

When you added the ldap server certificate into your cacerts, you don't need to do anything else. You can just make the call.

If you get PKIX exception when you make the call, then you need to make sure the CA and SubCA(s) of the ldap server certificate are trusted as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import private key to keystore.

Step1: You need to download openSSL and then move to `C:\OpenSSL-win64\bin` Next, type this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in C:\Keystore\certificate.crt -inkey C:\Keystore\name_key.key -out C:\Keystore\server.p12 -name [name_alias] -CAfile C:\Keystore\rootCA.crt -caname root
```

Note: if you use alias "tomcat" in `server.xml`

```
keyAlias="tomcat"

keystoreFile="C:\Keystore\server.jks"

keystorePass="your pass"

then [name_alias] = tomcat
```

Step 2: use cmd and move to `C:\program files\java\jdk..\ bin` and type this command to convert p12 file to jks file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass mypass -destkeystore C:\Keystore\server.jks -srckeystore C:\Keystore\server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

Restart your tomcat server